# Configuring the index.html basehref at ng build time

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I deploy my angular app to a subfolder at the server so the URL serving the app ends up as http://www.example.com/folder-name/ - which means the basehref has to be pointing to that folder at the index.html.

As a result of this fact, after running the `ng build --prod`, I have to modify the generated index.html manually each and evert time so the outputted file's `basehref=""` code is edited as `basehref="/folder-name/'`.

Is there any way to configure thru tsc config or some other tool so this is automated in a way that when I develop locally, the index.html would still continue to be `basehref=""` but when I run the `ng build` with the `--prod` flag, it comes out as `basehref="/folder-name/"`?

Also, (this is an independent question but), is there a way to automatically FTP the contents folder to the `sub-folder` of that server?

Thanks

Comment: The cli offers an option to add the basehref `ng build --base-href /folder-name/ --prod`. you could also use `-bh` as an alias for `--base-href`

Comment: thanks. want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cli offers an option to add the basehref during the build

```
ng build --base-href /folder-name/ --prod.
```

you can also use -bh as an alias for --base-href

Comment: thank you. I already suggested this to be a config setting for the angular-cli at their github page - cause it does not make sense to type this in every single time. But, wait, can't this be scripted out at the package.json just like npm start maps to ng serve?

Comment: @AverageJoe correct, I implement this by adding it to my package.json scripts. `"build-prod": "ng build --base-href /folder-name/ --aot --target=production --environment=prod"` so I can simply run `npm run build-prod`

Comment: @AverageJoe sifting through the documentation (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli), it looks like you can apply a baseHref in the angular-cli.json `{"build": {"baseHref": "folder-name"}}` but it looks like this is applied globally for both ng build & ng serve. So I think you are better off with the npm scripts.